# possible to take screenshot of <select> while open

Tags: focus, screenshot, html-select

We have a web page with a select box dropdown. I need to take a screenshot of the page with the select  dropdown "open". However, every time I press the printscreen button, the page loses focus and the select closes before it's able to take the screenshot. The screenshot always displays it closed or in the transition animation of it closing.

Is there a different way to take this screenshot, or maybe some way to force the select to stay open after the browser losing focus?

I'm using KDE Plasma 5.18.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the perfect solution, but I downloaded simplescreenrecorder, recorded the screen, then took a screenshot of the paused video with the select open.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use print screen button and a paint program? Try also Shift + PrtSc

Comment: I pressed the print screen button. As soon as I press it, the browser loses focus.I tried shift-print screen with the same results

Comment: @raphael75 Shift + PrintScreen works , the way you expected

Comment: In KDE when I press Shift + Printscreen nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Some screenshot programs has `delay` option. You can set timer, focus on the `select` option and wait for the timer.

I use https://apps.kde.org/spectacle/ in KDE.